# imshow shows different output than imwrite

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I was wondering how it is possible to save an image created by  `imshow` in matlab. The code below uses the `imshow` function with the min and max arguments specified - How can I apply this directly to the image itself instead of just specifying Matlab to show it?

```
maxBlur=3;

a = imshow(fDmap,[0 maxBlur]);

imwrite(a, 'img.png');
```

Writing to the file produces a different output to what is shown via `imshow`.

Can anyone suggest how to get the output from `imshow` saved as an image?

Answer (score 4):

To specify upper and lower intensity limits for [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) (similar to what you've done for `imshow`), you will want to use the second inputs to [`mat2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mat2gray.html) to adjust the contrast of your image prior to saving it with `imwrite`.

```
imwrite(mat2gray(fDmap, [0 maxBlur]), 'img.png');
```

If you literally want an image of what you're seeing with `imshow`, you can use [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) to take a screenshot. This will potentially be lower resolution than the previous approach and will also include whitespace around the image.

```
imshow(fDmap, [0 maxBlur]);
saveas(gcf, 'img.png');
```

> **NOTE**: The `a` variable that you passed to `imwrite` in your post is a [MATLAB graphics handle to an `image` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) that is used to manipulate the rendered image. `imwrite` expects image data in *matrix* form not as a graphics handle.